# SQL Many to Many Ranking

Tags: sql, count, many-to-many

I have 2 entities related with a many to many relationship

clients, services, clients_has_services.

I need to retrieve all services with their respective count of clients like so:

Service1 20
Service2 10
Service3 5
Service4 0
....

I'm having trouble making that query, this one only return one record:

```
SELECT
    services.id as id,
    services.name as name,
    COUNT(clients_has_services.services_id) as ranking
FROM services
LEFT JOIN clients_has_services ON services.id = clients_has_services.services_id
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a group by clause:

```
SELECT
    services.id as id,
    services.name as name,
    COUNT(clients_has_services.services_id) as ranking
FROM services
LEFT JOIN clients_has_services ON services.id = clients_has_services.services_id
GROUP BY
    services.id,
    services.name
```